# How to connect Android Development Device/Emulator to cygwin?

Tags: android, ant, android-ndk, cygwin, installation

I am trying to learn Android NDK using the Android NDK Beginners Guide book, when I came upon this step in chapter 2 to compile the hello-jni file. I can't figure out how to connect my Android dev device to cygwin teminal...can anyone help?

The step after this one in the book is ant install, and when I try that command the build fails. I'm assuming it's because I haven't connect the device to cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

The NDK is available for Windows, you don't need Cygwin, if this book is telling you to use Cygwin: switch to a better book!

http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

Comment: Am I missing something? From http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#Installing:  _"The NDK includes a set of cross-toolchains (compilers, linkers, etc..) that can generate native ARM binaries on Linux, OS X, and Windows  **(with Cygwin)** platforms."_